# Extract data of whole rows from multiple files if the range of values in column is satisfied

Tags: python, csv

I have multiple text/dst files,
[script1.dst, script2.dst, ..., script16.dst]

Every file contains 1600+ lines.

I want to extract the whole row of information if the value of the 6th column, i.e. Z is within the range of (10.3-10.8). If this condition is satisfied, I want to extract the whole row from that file and save the contents in my new file.

example input file: [script15.dst](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ey0y2.png)

```
import csv
fieldnames = ["A", "B", "C", "X", "Y", "Z"]
filenames = ["script1.dst", "script2.dst"]
with open("inner sphere.txt", "w") as inner, open("outer sphere.txt", "w") as outer: 
    writer inner = csv.DictWriter(inner, fieldnames, dialect="excel-tab")
    writer outer = csv.DictWriter(outer, fieldnames, dialect="excel-tab")
    writer inner.writeheader()
    writer outer.writeheader()
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename, "r") as input:
            reader = csv.DictReader(input, dialect="excel-tab")
            for row in reader:
                if 10.3 <= int(row["Z"]) <= 10.8:
                    writer inner.writerow(row)
                else:
                    writer outer.writerow(row)
```

Thanks,
Deb

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Congratulations on your first post. What have you tried? Add your code and any errors/output to your question and that will help others find solutions to your problem. It may be helpful to you to read: [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Folks here typically expect a 'minimal reproducible example'.

Comment: I looked at the picture of your code. (Btw text of code would be better ^^). You used int() to convert to a number but you want to compare decimal number so you must use float().

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to slightly recast your problem statement so that the solution is concise. Please comment if this explanation is not clear.

First I create fake data since I do not have your original data:

```
import pandas
print(pandas.__version__)
import numpy
print(numpy.__version__)
df = pandas.DataFrame(numpy.random.randint(0,100,size=(2000, 4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['E'] = df['A']/10 + 5
df.head()
```

That dataframe contains 5 columns. The `E` column has values in the range 5 to 15 and are floats.  I can find values in a range using

```
gt = df['E']>10.3
lt = df['E']<10.8
df[gt & lt]
```

The output is the set of rows that meet the criterion that column `E` values are between 10.3 and 10.8